# TextureCache::addImageAsync selector typecast issue

Tags: c++, ios, cocos2d-x

I'm trying to use addImageAsync for the first time, but i cannot get the syntax working. I'm using Cocos2dx 3.3 final and Xcode 6.1.1.
My code is as follows :

(GFXManager.h)

```
#include "cocos2d.h"  
class GFXManager  
{  
  ...  
  void loadStuff();  
  void textureLoaded(Ref* pObj);  
}
```

(GFXManager.cpp)

```
...
void GFXManager::loadStuff()  
{  
  std::string path = "whatever.png";    
  Director::getInstance()->getTextureCache()->addImageAsync(path, callfuncO_selector(GFXManager::textureLoaded));  
}  

void GFXManager::textureLoaded(Ref* pObj)  
{  
  ...  
}
```

The above is based on the "Texture2dTest" sample from Cocos2dx.
But at the line with the addImageAsync instruction Xcode keeps saying this:

**Static_cast from 'void (GFXManager::*)(cocos2d::Ref * )' to 'cocos2d::SEL_CallFuncO' (aka 'void (cocos2d::Ref::*)(cocos2d::Ref *)') is not allowed**

I tried making 'GFXManager' a class derived from 'Layer' (as in Texture2dTest), and using 'CCObject' in place of 'Ref' (as in Texture2dTest...But 'CCObject' is deprecated and now it is called 'Ref'), with no luck.

But every example i've found on the web about using addImageAsync calls the selector with that syntax.
So what am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change `callfuncO_selector` with `std::bind` or `CC_CALLBACK_1`:

```
void GFXManager::loadStuff()  
{  
    std::string path = "whatever.png";    
    Director::getInstance()->getTextureCache()->addImageAsync(path, CC_CALLBACK_1(GFXManager::textureLoaded, this));  
}
```

because TextureCache::addImageAsync accepts `std::function` not the function pointer